# Театр, как понятие; театр, как консерватория или филармония, - запятые перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

> — Будущее театра в России – каким вы его представляете?
>
> — Несомненно, он должен перейти в новое качество. **Театр, как
>   понятие, к которому мы привыкли**, мне кажется, умирает. Если
>   сравнивать его с музыкой, то **театр, как консерватория или
>   филармония**: его посещение — это всегда затраты, определенная
>   эмоциональная нагрузка.

Первое как = будучи, второе - сравнение?

Но что такое театр-понятие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое - аспект, в котором рассматривается театр (не надо запятой, ср. "театр как понятие /как "класс"/ умирает), второе - уподобление, причём за словом "театр" следует именное сказуемое, поэтому не запятая, а тире, заменяющее подразумеваемую связку "есть" (**театр - как консерватория или филармония:**).

Comment: В оригинале было: ***Если сравнивать его с музыкой, то театр, как консерватория или филармония — его посещение это всегда затраты...*** Мне нужно было тире перед "это", потому и двоеточие моё. И чё я спортила? по эмоционально-смысловой нагрузке?

Comment: Здесь запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым, а два тире (если заменить одним запятую) не приживаются, поэтому двоеточие напрашивается.

Comment: Не, ну ты заметил наконец, какая я умная? И пишу без ошибок! Я только правил совсем не знаю: практик мы.